# Get URL of Featured Image After wp_insert_post()

Tags: php, uploads

I want to get the url of a featured image.

I've created a function with `wp_insert_post` to post data and set a featured image for them. Everything works fine except displaying the url of featured image.

Here is my code :

```
$newpostname = $movie['title'];

global $wpdb;

$id_ofpost_name     = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = '$newpostname'" );
$id_ofpost_title    = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '$newpostname'" );

if( $id_ofpost_name || $id_ofpost_title ) { echo 'post Exist'; } 
else {
    // Register Post Data
    $post                   = array();
    $post['post_status']    = 'publish';
    $post['post_type']      = 'post';               // can be a CPT too
    $post['post_title']     = $newpostname;
    $post['post_content']   = '';
    $post['post_author']    = 1;

    // Create Post
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );

    // Add Featured Image to Post
    $image_url  = $movie['urlPoster'];
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();                  // Set upload folder
    $image_data = file_get_contents( $image_url );  // Get image data
    $filename   = basename( $image_url );           // Create image file name

    // Check folder permission and define file location
    if( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
        $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
    } else {
        $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
    }

    // Create the image  file on the server
    file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );

    // Check image file type
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );

    // Set attachment data
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    );

    // Create the attachment
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );

    // Include image.php
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

    // Define attachment metadata
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );

    // Assign metadata to attachment
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    // And finally assign featured image to post
    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
}
```

The post inserting works perfectly! The problem is that I want to get the url of featured image after upload. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well you have the ID as `$attach_id` so you can use a function such as [`wp_get_attachment_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) where you can pass `$attach_id` and get a url returned:

```
$featured_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attach_id );
```

Or if you want more information such as width, height, etc. you can use functions like [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) or [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata).

Comment: it's not working. is it even possible get featured image url after wp_insert_post function ?

Comment: There shouldn't be a reason why it *doesn't* work after `wp_insert_post()`.  Can you it through `function_exists()` to see if the `wp_get_attachment_url()` exists at that point? I'm not sure where you code is but usually you wouldn't need to include `wp-admin/includes/image.php`. Maybe mock up a simpler insert post in your theme to narrow down the issue. `fucntion_exists( 'wp_get_attachment_url' );`

Comment: ok Im going to try that and let you know tge result. thanks